# Empty formset passing validation but not saving records

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

My setup involves a form where a Game instance and Teams tied the Game are created.  The set of teams tied to the game are entered in a formset called GameTeamsFormset.

My problem is, sometimes the fields in the GameTeamsFormset are empty, which *should* create empty records in my database (yes, I want this) but no records actually get created even though the formset passes validation and I'm able to add these empty records manually through the admin.  (Well, they're not completely empty since they have a foreign key tying them to the Game instance).  So, how to I get my view to save records for each of the empty forms in my formset?

Views.py

```
def addGame(request, league_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        league = League.objects.get(pk = league_id) # get the league object
        gameform = GameForm(request.POST) # initialize gameform with the POST data
        if gameform.is_valid():
            newgame = gameform.save(commit=False)
            newgame.league = league # set the league

            gameteamsform = GameTeamsFormset(request.POST, instance=newgame)
            if gameteamsform.is_valid():
                newgame.save() # save the game
                gameteamsform.save()
                return editleague(request, league_id)

            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/") #needs fixin
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/") #needs fixin
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/") #needs fixin
```

Forms.py

```
class GameForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['game_heading', 'game_date', 'game_time']
        widgets = {
            'game_heading':TextInput(attrs={'type':'text', 'class':'form-control input-md'}),
            'game_date':TextInput(attrs={'type':'date', 'class':'form-control'}),
            'game_time':TextInput(attrs={'type':'time', 'class':'form-control'}),
        }


GameTeamsFormset = inlineformset_factory(Game, GameTeams, extra=2,
    fields=['team', 'placed', 'score'],
    widgets={'team': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
             'placed': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
             'score': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})},
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FormSets are designed to ignore empty records. you'll have to save individually (and perhaps set the related key).

so in your post code:

```
if request.POST:
    forms_factory = modelformset_factory(...)
    forms = forms_factory(request.POST)
    if forms.is_valid():
        for form in forms:
            form.instance.game = newgame
            form.save()
```

I believe this will also iterate through the blank forms returned.

```
def addGame(request, league_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        league = League.objects.get(pk = league_id) # get the league object
        gameform = GameForm(request.POST) # initialize gameform with the POST data
        if gameform.is_valid():
            newgame = gameform.save(commit=False)
            newgame.league = league # set the league

            gameteamsform = GameTeamsFormset(request.POST, instance=newgame)
            if gameteamsform.is_valid():
                newgame.save() # save the game
                for gameteam in gameteamsform:
                    gameteam.game = newgame
                    gameteam.save()
                gameteamsform.save()
                return editleague(request, league_id)

            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/") #needs fixin
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/") #needs fixin
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/") #needs fixin
```